# iOS: Add timezone without changing/converting the time value

Tags: ios, date, nsdate

Hi need help with timezone, I need to change it without changing timestamp like so:
"2019-01-25T11:55:00+00:00" -> "2019-01-25T11:55:00-08:00"

Here is what I am getting:
"2019-01-25T11:55:00+00:00" timestamp, 00:00 is incorrect and I need to change it to specific timezone that I am getting for example -08:00 to get "2019-01-25T11:55:00-08:00"

I am using dateFormatter with this date format : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"
tried decouple whole timestamp by dateComponents and rebuild it again after, tz added but time changed also (

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible you are misunderstanding how this works? A timestamp such as `"2019-01-25T11:55:00+00:00"` specifically means that it happened at 11:55:00 in the UTC timezone. That same exact moment in the -08:00 timezone was at 3:55:00, not 11:50:00. Why do you want to change the timezone but keep the same time? That's just seems wrong.

Comment: I am getting timestamp: "2019-01-25T11:55:00+00:00" and timeZone as "America/Los_Angeles" separately, so this 11:55 already in that timezone, I just need replace +00:00 in timestamp with right one

Comment: That's really strange that you get the timezone identifier as a string separate from a timestamp that specifically states it is in the UTC timezone. So your goal is to ignore the timezone specified in the timestamp and to use the other timezone given to you separately, correct?

Comment: @rmaddy, if I had to guess, I’d say it’s like a poorly written JSON API that I had to work with once, where the API returned timestamps without time zones in server local time, and then when parsing, the receiver parsed the lack of time zone as UTC, and now he’s trying to tell Swift that actually the time zone is not UTC, it’s America/Los_Angeles.

Comment: @Kirill if I’m at all right in that last statement, I’d say try your hardest to get your API to be changed to return UTC timestamps with a time zone clearly indicated.

Comment: Yes, exactly ignore the timezone specified in the timestamp and use the other timezone that coming separately without changing time itself

Comment: @Nate yes I just need to correct UTC tz to right one without changing time

Comment: @rmaddy to clarify, the API I dealt with was returning timestamps without time zones, such as "2019-01-25T11:55:00" the fact that this API returns them with "+00:00" at the end, even though that’s not accurate astounds me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you need to ignore the timezone provided in the timestamp string and to replace it with a timezone identifier, you can use code like the following:

```
let timezone = "America/Los_Angeles"
let timestamp = "2019-01-25T11:55:00+00:00"

let df = DateFormatter()
df.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: timezone)
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

let date = df.date(from: String(timestamp.dropLast(6)))
```

This sets up the date formatter using the additional timezone while parsing a timestamp that doesn't have any timezone (removed using the `dropLast(6)`).

This code gives you a `Date` representing January 25, 2019 at 11:55:00 in the LA timezone. Keep in mind that if you simply print `date` it will show you the date in UTC. This is simply the output of printing a `Date`.

Please note that the actual correct solution is to get the timestamp string with the correct timezone from the API to begin with. You should not have to jump through hoops like this to get a correct timestamp.

Comment: Solid workaround. And +1 for saying that the API should have been done right in the first place.

Comment: @rmaddy Thanks for that, and yes I agree with point that it should have been corrected by API.

Answer (score 0):

So here with what I endup

Date:

```
extension Date {
  public func dateWithAdjusted(timeZone: String, date: String) -> String {
    let timeZoneIdentifier = TimeZone(identifier: timeZone)?.identifier

    guard let timezoneId = timeZoneIdentifier else { return "" }
    let timeZoneOffset = TimeZone.getOffset(from: timezoneId)

    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "([+-])([0-9]{2}[:]{1}[0-9]{2})", options: .caseInsensitive)
    let range = NSMakeRange(0,date.count)
    let newTimeStamp = regex.stringByReplacingMatches(in: date, options: [], range: range, withTemplate: timeZoneOffset)

    return newTimeStamp
  }
```

and Timezone:

```
extension TimeZone {
  public static func getOffset(from identifier: String) -> String {
    let timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: identifier)

    guard let tz = timeZone else { return getOffset(from: TimeZone.current.identifier ) }

    let seconds = tz.secondsFromGMT()
    let hours = seconds/3600
    let minutes = abs(seconds/60) % 60

    let timeZoneOffset = String(format: "%+.2d:%.2d", hours, minutes)

    return timeZoneOffset
  }
```

```
let adjustedTimestamp = Date().dateWithAdjusted(timeZone:"America/New_York", date: "2019-01-26T02:55:00+00:00")

Output: "2019-01-26T02:55:00-05:00"
```